# Showing custom tab menu only on customer edit issue

Tags: layout, magento-1

This is my code from my layout:

```
    <adminhtml_customer_edit>
        <reference name="customer_edit_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>tabname</name>
                <block>mynamespace_mymodule/adminhtml_customer_tab_tickets</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_customer_edit>
```

I want to hide this tab if I create a new customer and only show on customer edit. How can I do that ? thx

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to set 'block' variable dynamically via helper. Below is how the code will look like.

**layout:**

```
<adminhtml_customer_edit>
    <reference name="customer_edit_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>tabname</name>
            <block helper="mynamespace_mymodule/getTabBlock" />
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_customer_edit>
```

**Mynamespace_Mymodule_Helper_Data:**

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function getTabBlock()
    {
        $currentCustomer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
        if ($currentCustomer &&  $currentCustomer->getId()) {
            return 'mynamespace_mymodule/adminhtml_customer_tab_tickets';
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what will happen with my block ? adminhtml_customer_tab_tickets, defined in the xml ?

Comment: As you can see, the block name will by returned by Mynamespace_Mymodule_Helper_Data::getTabBlock() . In case, you are editing existing customer, it will return 'mynamespace_mymodule/adminhtml_customer_tab_tickets'. And in case of creating a new cstomer, it will return an empty array.